# How can i stop a custom CSS from overwriting my styles?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

**Problem**

I have a site built with my own styles and it looks just the way I like it. However, I want to add extra functionality by adding a custom dialog box downloaded from [BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com/).

However the extensive style sheet that comes with it and is needed absolutely murders my site, butchering it in every way.

Is there anyway i can stop this by making the BootBox.css only apply to its little part of my code and not all of my site?

Comment: you site uses twitter bootstrap library?

Comment: @LeonardoDelfino, yes

Comment: Where you downloaded the file bootbox.css? For version 4.2.0 on the site, the download area only the js file is indicated for download.

Comment: I do apologise, bootstrap.css not bootbox.css!

Comment: @DanCundy I was wondering.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LESS wich is what bootstrap uses.

Example:

```
#ContainerWithBootboox {      
   @import (less) "bootstrap.css"; //import bootstrap
}
```

Doc: http://lesscss.org/

Comment: beat me by 5 sec :D !

Comment: Ok so i had a quick look at the less page, which to be honest looked a little beyond my current capabilities. But from looking at your example it would seem that you would encase your bootbox code in a div. Then give the divs style all the styles from the bootstrap.css?

Comment: Yes you can create a div with a class bootbox-container, the container would contain the rules of the bootstrap, so the bootbox components created within it will work without breaking the rest of the layout. For each component modal bootbox created will need to put it as a child of a div with the class-container bootbox

Comment: Ok do i need to download/install/include "LESS"? I'm going to go with this solution, just want to get a better idea of how it works. and What i need to do to get started. I tried something similar to your example and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: ok i'm going bed, will delve into the workings of LESS tomorrow and update tomorrow on how i get on. Thank you all for the point in the right direction.

Comment: @LeonardoDelfino I have implemented your solution and it works as it should, however i have come to realise that the bootstrap.css need to be applied to the whole page and not just in the confines of a container as it styles other parts of my page once active.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the bootbox css to target a specific div, you'd need to prepend each bootbox css rule with the class of the target div.

So if you had

```
<div class="bootbox">
   <!-- bootbox html here -->
</div>
```

and the bootbox styles were

```
h1 {
   color: red;
   padding: 0;
}

h2 {
   color: blue;
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Then you'd need to change it to

```
.bootbox h1 {
   color: red;
   padding: 0;
}

.bootbox h2 {
   color: blue;
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

That said, if the bootbox css is thousands of lines of code then this may be labour intensive. It might be a matter of finding which rules specifically are borking your code and adding a specifier class to only those rules.

Comment: This looks promising, and makes sense, but as you said is going to take a while as line count is 5080! :(

Comment: Though what is probably happening is that the bootbox css is that you're using two different versions of bootstrap on your site, one for the whole site and one just for bootbox. Have a look at the dependencies for bootbox (http://bootboxjs.com/#dependencies) to see if there is a version conflict.

Comment: Including the entire bootstrap css library twice on your page is going to have some negative performance effects :)

Answer (score 1):

Not labour intensive, with the help of [LESS](http://lesscss.org) or [SASS] (http://sass-lang.com),

If you use LESS, just wrap all bootbox css rules inside a parent root. For e.g.:

```
.bootbox {
    /*move all bootbox CSS rules here*/
    h1 { color: inherit;}
    .someclass { color: red;}
}
```

It will be compiled into:

```
.bootbox .h1 { color: inherit }
.bootbox .someclass {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the BootBox code within an iframe.  The css loaded by the iframe would only apply to the content within the iframe.  I have used this strategy to only apply bootstrap to certain areas of my page such as tables, while leaving the rest of the page untouched.

Comment: I'm guessing you would have to them position the iframe in your css to where you want it to appear?

Comment: Using an iframe in this case may be overkill. Plus it may not work at all, seeing as the bootbox markup needs to overlay the entire page.

Comment: @DanCundy Yes, you would need to position the iframe.

Comment: @KevinBowersox from my experience, iframe to fix CSS is not going to end well. There'll be more hassle in modifying your selector

Comment: @loop_duplicate, I think you are correct, just tried the iframe solution and it didn't work, maybe because i didn't implement it properly or like you said....